# How would I achieve a hover effect which changes a photo in one location? Like a photo viewer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, photo, photo-gallery

You can see in my attached image, one of the buttons/icons has the same photo as the large picture, if I hover over the other buttons/icons the large picture should also change. This seems redundant and indeed this is not what I intend to do but shows the effect I'm trying to accomplish. The only thing I have to go on is the mouseover effect for hovering over an image which changes but how do you have the secondary image show up elsewhere other than the current picture itself?

[image]

**-- update --**

I want to have a photo preview where if you hover over multiple divs or images, a larger one changes to show a preview.

Is that css or javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on your HTML, could be both/either. Try and build a demo first and ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: Can be done with both show us what you have done and what problem you have faced in doing it we would help you out

Comment: posted a photo to show somewhat what I am trying to achieve

Comment: So for example if you hover your mouse over the 3D Airplane, you wan to see the main (big) image change to that of the 3D Airplane?

Comment: Yes but again that isn't what I would do but that is the idea. Thank you for your response.

Comment: found this : http://www.wickham43.net/hoverpopups.php